# Facebook ID from URL, with error exception?

Tags: php, facebook

So I am making a PHP app that asks for the users Facebook (in those exact terms) I want it to be able to handle the copy and past Facebook URL as well as well as simply just their user name. I found this:

```
function GetUsernameFromFacebookURL($url) {
$correctURLPattern = '/^https?:\/\/(?:www|m)\.facebook.com\/(?:profile\.php\?id=)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$/';
if (!preg_match($correctURLPattern, $url, $matches)) {
    throw new Exception('Not a valid URL');
}

return $matches[1];
```

The above code is really good at handling:

```
https://www.facebook.com/JohnDoe
https://m.facebook.com/sally.struthers
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=24353623
```

But I would like it to return the input value if no URL is inserted, how do I do this? In addition, I notice a lot of Facebook URLs have additional arguments, such as; https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ufi - how do I compensate for that?

Comment: you do know that scraping is not allowed on facebook, right? anyway, why not just replace https://www.facebook.com/, https://m.facebook.com/ and https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id= ?

Comment: Don’t throw an exception then, but put `return $url;` in that place instead …?

Comment: Tanks CBroe, I added an additional question - In addition, I notice a lot of Facebook URLs have additional arguments, such as; https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ufi - how do I compensate for that?